# SQL Server correlated query want to take sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

```
select 
    SUM(Convert(int, (Select SUM(Convert(int, amount)) 
                       from ChargesType 
                       where ChargesType.ID = Charges.ChargesTypeID))) as Amount 
from Charges 
Where Charges.RollNo = 1
```

This is my query; I want to get sum of amount column.

Comment: Do you really have an amount column which is not numeric?

Comment: yes it is nvarchar type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
select 
    SUM(t.Amount) as Amount 
from Charges AS c
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT Convert(int, amount) AS Amount, ID
   FROM  ChargesType
) AS t ON t.ID = c.ChargesTypeID
Where c.RollNo = 1
```